# how to certain remove string from list in dataframe? very basic python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I want to remove certain string from a list form in Dataframe.

I declared a list and I wanna remove these 3 words in dataframe.

Each sentence from list in dataframe is all separated as word and I don't know how to remove it...

```
lst = ['I','There','people']


|      Token                |   
|---------------------------|
|['I', 'like', 'apple']     |    
|['There', 'are', 'people'] |  
|['she','likes','apple']    |
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
list_ = ['I','There','people']

temp = pd.DataFrame({'Token':[
    ['I', 'like', 'apple'],
    ['There', 'are', 'people'],
    ['he','likes','apple']
]}) 
temp['Token'].apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y not in list_])
```

Output:

```
0         [like, apple]
1                 [are]
2    [he, likes, apple]
Name: Token, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, use a list comprehension:

```
S = set(lst)
temp['Token'] = [[w for w in x if w not in S]
                 for x in temp['Token']]
```

Output:

```
                Token
0       [like, apple]
1               [are]
2  [he, likes, apple]
```